Encountering this AvroRuntimeException when windowing is introduced. How can I resolve this issue while using GenericRecord with windowing in Beam?
Problem:
I'm encountering an error when trying to use windowing with Avro's GenericRecord in Apache Beam. The error I'm getting is:
Code Snippet:
Here’s the code that produces the error:
PCollection<KV<KV<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>, Boolean>> windowedOutput = inputRecords
    .apply(Window.<KV<KV<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>, Boolean>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
    .setCoder(KvCoder.of(
        KvCoder.of(
            AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, keySchema),
            AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, valueSchema)
        ),
        BooleanCoder.of()
    ));

This throws the AvroRuntimeException mentioned above when applied.
Working Example:
The following similar code (without windowing) works just fine:
PCollection<KV<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>> outputRecords = input
    .apply(ParDo.of(new ConvertToAvroFn(keySchema, valueSchema)))
    .setCoder(KvCoder.of(
        AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, keySchema),
        AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, valueSchema)
    ));

[ERROR] Encountered an exception, shutting down the process {}
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a Specific class: interface org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.createSchema(SpecificData.java:396) ~[avro-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData.createSchema(ReflectData.java:726) ~[avro-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData$3.computeValue(SpecificData.java:328) ~[avro-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:227) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:209) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:115) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchema(SpecificData.java:339) ~[avro-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.of(AvroCoder.java:163) ~[beam-sdks-java-core-2.45.22.jar:?]
    at com.example.pipeline.CustomSink.applyCustomCheck(CustomSink.java:247)
    at com.example.pipeline.CustomSink.expand(CustomSink.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:551)


I suspect this is not related to windowing, but just that some difference in the two pipelines means that the AvroCoder is being fused away. In other words any time it is used you will see this failure. See https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/pipeline-lifecycle#fusion_optimization

Sorry, I did not understand how fusion would be at play here? I did read the docs which you shared, but any idea about how fusion is causing "Not a Specific class" issue?
Can you please elaborate more?

If steps A and B are fused, then the code in between the steps is never invoked, so it will mask the error. This only applies to running on Dataflow. Are you testing this on the DirectRunner as well? That would rule out the issue I'm describing.

The constructor AvroCoder.of expects to receive your data class rather than GenericRecord. In other words if you can, write your pipeline fragment like so:
PCollection<KV<KV<MyKeyClass, MyValueClass>, Boolean>> windowedOutput = inputRecords
.apply(Window.<KV<KV<MyKeyClass, MyValueClass>, Boolean>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
.setCoder(KvCoder.of(
    KvCoder.of(
        AvroCoder.of(MyKeyClass.class, keySchema),
        AvroCoder.of(MyValueClass.class, valueSchema)
    ),
    BooleanCoder.of()
));


The way our code is structured I'd have to use GenericRecord.
In fact if you'd see, this is working:
PCollection<KV<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>> outputRecords = input
.apply(ParDo.of(new ConvertToAvroFn(keySchema, valueSchema)))
.setCoder(KvCoder.of(
AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, keySchema),
AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, valueSchema)
));
PS: Any idea why?
